# What's the difference between "share issue" vs "public offering"

Tags: phrase-meaning

These two definitions are from Cambridge Dictionary:

**share issue**
an occasion when a company makes new shares available for sale, or the number of shares offered:

**Public offering**
an occasion when a company makes shares available, or the number of shares made available:

Are these interchangeable. Thesaurus lists "initial public offering" &
"new securities issue" as synonyms for **"Public offering"** Does this mean that **"public offering"** is only when a company makes stock available to the public for the first time and "**share issue**" is used for consequent stocks that are made available?

Comment: This seems to be more of a economics question than an English question. Most people will not have knowledge of this. "Public offering" could be used for an initial offering or a later offering, but a "share issue" is usually only used for offerings after the initial one. Most people refer to the initial offering as "going public" so "public offering" is not very common. That being said, as a stock market enthusiast, I have never heard these used, the term that is instead used is "capital raising" meaning they are selling more shares to raise capital. it is used for initial or other offerings.

Comment: "Share issue" would more refer to the actual act of issuing them like: "the share issue will happen at 1pm" but since no one usually talks about these specifics it would be more common to hear "company abcxyz is raising capital again, this time for 1 million shares."

Comment: I agree "share issue" refers to the actual mechanics of creating new shares without specifically referring to the motivation for creating them.